# Get Continent from LAT-LONG in JS only?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

OK I am using a hosted e-commerce solution, and i need to locate the user to the continent using Javascript I've got the LAT-LONG using the geoloacte HTML API like so:

```
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
```

So how do ui go about cross referencing this to get the continent two letter code? 
Chris

Comment: Get a map and look up in which continent-polygon the coordinates are located.

Comment: an example? maybe a Jquery library? a tutorial or similar?

Comment: No jQuery library, since this does have nothing to do with the DOM. Search for some geodetic library instead. However I don't think you need such especial precision, so simple geometrics will do.

Answer (score 1):

I used this link to download shape files and than convert them to format that i need them with some GIS tools so later i can do queries on that data to get what i need hope this help http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/